# Get a series of data based on dataframe split

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
Cat | Val
 A  | 10
 B  | 20
 B  | 5
 A  | 8
```

I want to split columns into

```
[[10, 8],[20,5]]
[A,B]
```

I know this is super simple, just cant find the right online resource for it

Answer (score 2):

By using `groupby` `apply` and `list`

```
s=df.groupby('Cat').Val.apply(list)
s.index.tolist()
Out[273]: ['A', 'B']
s.values.tolist()
Out[274]: [[10, 8], [20, 5]]

s.reset_index()
Out[276]: 
  Cat      Val
0   A  [10, 8]
1   B  [20, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below code. First `groupby` on the column of interest:

```
gb = df.groupby(by=['Cat'])
```

Now you can do the following for `Cat` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html) is dry but as you can see it's a dict and keys are group names.)

```
list(gb.groups.keys())
```

Output

```
['A', 'B']
```

And for `Val` we can get the subdf from each group and get the column of our interest as a list.

```
[list(gb.get_group(x)['Val']) for x in gb.groups]
```

Gives

```
[[10, 8], [20, 5]]
```